# Strange get-only issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an internal variable:

```
internal var categories: Set<MyCategory>? {
    if let a = self.a {
        return a
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

but when I try to set Array to this Set as:

```
self.categories = Set(myArray)
```

it rises the error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'categories' is a get-only property

I really do not understand why this error appears! Can someone explain me what happens there? Maybe I have empty spots in my Swift knowledge

Comment: You cannot modify the value of a computed variable like that, since it's not a stored property.

Comment: where is the _strange_-part, exactly?

Comment: @holex vadian understood me perfectly and helped me with his advice! Thanks for your minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration is a short form of

```
internal var categories: Set<MyCategory>? {
    get {
        if let a = self.a {
            return a
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

a **read-only computed property**.

By the way your syntax can be still more shortened

```
internal var categories: Set<MyCategory>? {
    return self.a
}
```

---

A computed property with getter and setter could look like

```
internal var categories: Set<MyCategory>? {
    get {
       return self.a
    }
    set {
       self.a = newValue
    }
}
```

but **NEVER** like this, this syntax will call the setter which calls the setter which calls the setter which calls the setter which calls the setter which calls the setter which calls the setter which calls the setter ... which calls the setter which **crashes**

```
internal var categories: Set<MyCategory>? {
    ...
    set {
       categories = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! It helped me! So I need just add setter to it

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is showing error because you are trying to set value on read-only computed properties. If you want to set some values to other properties you should create setter for it as explained below.

In swift there are two types of properties: **Stored and Computed** properties.

Stored propeties

> a stored property is a constant or variable that is stored as part of
>   an instance of a particular class or structure. Stored properties can
>   be either variable stored properties (introduced by the var keyword)
>   or constant stored properties (introduced by the let keyword).

Computed Properties

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and
>   enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually
>   store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter
>   to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

So, computed properties do not store value instead they calculate value from other properties(if required) and provide getter method to retrieve computed value and an optional setter method to set values to other properties.

For example:

```
var seconds:Double = 0
var minutes: Double {
    get {
        return (seconds / 60)
    }
    set {
        seconds = (newValue * 60)
    }
}
```

Here property `seconds` is Stored property and `minutes` is Computed property.
To access minutes getter method is provided and to update setter is defined which does not store value instead it calculates `seconds` and update variable `seconds` when minutes are updated.

If you want to have a read-only computed variable then simply remove `set {}` method.

Read-Only Computed Properties

> A computed property with a getter but no
>   setter is known as a read-only computed property. A read-only computed
>   property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot
>   syntax, but cannot be set to a different value.

You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces:

For example:

```
var minutes: Double {
    return (seconds / 60)
}
```

This is what you have done in your code.

```
internal var categories: Set<MyCategory>? {
    if let a = self.a {
        return a
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

To set value you need to define setter for computed property `categories`.

For more detail please refer to [Apple doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)